# When i move a file from raw folder to SD card in android, the file won't move

Tags: android

I used the following code to move the audio file form `res/raw` folder to SD card, when i execute this code, the file won't move. why it will happens, in which line i made mistake.

**MoveAudio.java**

```
public class MoveAudioextends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                byte[] buffer = null;
                InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources()
                        .openRawResource(R.raw.song);
                int size = 0;
                System.out.println("<<<<<<<SIZE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + fIn);
                try {
                    size = fIn.available();
                    System.out
                            .println("<<<<<<<SIZE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + size);
                    buffer = new byte[size];
                    fIn.read(buffer);
                    fIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
                String path = "/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
                String filename = "examplefile" + ".ogg";

                boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
                if (!exists) {
                    System.out
                            .println("<<<<<<<FALSE SO INSIDE THE CONDITION>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                    new File(path).mkdirs();
                }

                FileOutputStream save;
                try {
                    save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
                    System.out
                            .println("<<<<<<<SAVE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + save);
                    save.write(buffer);
                    save.flush();
                    save.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));

                File k = new File(path, filename);
                System.out.println("<<<<<<<SAVE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + k);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In my xml file i had sing button, when i click that button the file will move. This code executes without error but the file won't move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having empty catch blocks, try instead to write those out.

```
e.printStackTrace();
// I believe it is.
```

Additionally, have you permissions to write to the SD Card?

```
permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the filename of the song in your resource folder? The reason i ask is that there is a max file size that can be read back for a file that is compressed. Your file, if named with a .ogg extension shouldn't be compressed and thus not constrained to this limit. However if you named it something else that gets compressed it may have this problem.

A good way to log errors is to use androids Log methods. Do so like this:

```
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException", e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);

  }
```

You may be getting a "Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (1290892 vs 1048576)" message.

The only way to tell for sure though is to log your error. It is also possible the SD card is out of space or you don't have permissions to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, my raw file is "test.pdf"
We will use "Download" folder in our phone.
"test.pdf" in raw folder will be moved to "Download/test_filemove" folder as "example.pdf"
Make the new "raw" folder in "res" folder.
Copy "test.pdf" to "raw" folder.

Surely you should make Button01 in your layout.

Don't forget to give permission in your manifest file as below

> `</application>
>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>`

I just modify your example a little bit.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.test);
            int size = 0;
            System.out.println("<<<<<<<SIZE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + fIn);
            try {
                size = fIn.available();
                System.out
                        .println("<<<<<<<SIZE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + size);
                buffer = new byte[size];
                fIn.read(buffer);
                fIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }

            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/test_filemove/";

            String filename = "example" + ".pdf";

            boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
            if (!exists) {
                System.out
                        .println("<<<<<<<FALSE SO INSIDE THE CONDITION>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                new File(path).mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream save;
            try {
                save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
                System.out
                        .println("<<<<<<<SAVE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + save);
                save.write(buffer);
                save.flush();
                save.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
}`

I hope this help you out.